# I need a RegExp to only match Latin characters and not else

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have written the following code to check if the given string is Latin or it contains some other non-latin chars like Persian. The issue is that it always returns true for both of the following strings:

```
$str = "Hello, What's up?"
```

Or

```
$str = "Hello, سلام"
```

While for the second string it should return false since it contains Persian characters (non-latin) too.

```
$default_rule = "/[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\*_\-\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\,\.\"\'\]\[]*/";
    $rule  = ($rule==null) ? $default_rule : $rule;

    if(preg_match($rule, $str)==true)
    {
        // always returns true
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Your pattern will return true if the string contains *zero or more* of those characters you've specified. In other words, it will return true for *any* string at all. You need to put start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around it. Also you don't need to escape most of those characters (the character class causes them to be treated as literal characters):

```
$default_rule = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9()*_\-!#$%^&*,."\'\][]*$/';
```

But, this will match an empty string. To also make sure that the string is not empty, use the `+` quantifier (one or more) instead of `*`.

```
$default_rule = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9()*_\-!#$%^&*,."\'\][]+$/';
```

Comment: thank you so much. I did semi-lazi match :D .... your answer made many things clear though

Comment: Too bad he doesn't want all basic ASCII chars... Looking at the table, I see we could go with a tidy `^[ -~]+$` :)  +1